# What could cause iOS Universal Links to stop working?

Tags: ios, hyperlink, universal

I had Universal Links working on my iOS 9 app. If I clicked on a UL from an email or text message, it would launch my app as expected.

Then I added a QR Code Reader and used openURL() open the UL embedded in the QR Code from within my app (which was supposed to be handled by the app itself).

On one test run, the URL embedded in the QR code was malformed: it had a CR/LF at the end of it, and when the app tried to open it, it crashed (I do not have the crash log/trace unfortunately).

As I researched the crash I realized that openURL() is not designed to work with UL, so I fixed the code to have my app handle the URL differently, but now none of the ULs work with my app anymore: what used to work from an email or text message doesn't anymore (it launches Safari instead of my app).

I install my app via TestFlight and I can see from my backend that the apple-app-site-association file is being pulled, but it still won't work.

Important data (that's how I know the problem is with the state on that specific phone): the **same app** on a **different phone** opens ULs **correctly**.
It's as if the one bug I ran into put the phone in a state that will always launch Safari for those URLs no matter what.

It is the only phone that exhibits this problem.

What I tried without success:

- uninstalling the app completely
- reboot

Not sure what to try next. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Weird that it's not working on one phone but is on another. Are the iOS versions the same? I'm having issues getting this working as well. Did you get it to work?

Comment: It started working after a while (nothing special that I did: my guess is the phone went into some kind of "flush caches" or "reset" process at some point, and it started working again).

Answer (score 1):

You probably clicked on the link in the top right corner of the status bar to open one of your ULs in Safari. After that all subsequent ULs will open in Safari.

In Safari, pull down the page until you see the Smart-App-Banner at the top. Then click on 'Open' and ULs should work again.

Comment: thanks! but I haven't implemented any smart banner on my backend, so nothing's showing... but you're giving me a great idea -> support smart banners! that may help unwedge my phone out of that state

Comment: Also this doesn't seem to work for devbuilds anymore. The smart app banner points at the live build so once you install the dev build, it says 'View' and takes you to the app store instead of opening the dev build =(